# How to run sql scripts against mariaDB docker container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am trying to create a mariadb instance in docker and then run all the files in a directory against it. I know my script works when I execute it after my dockerfile runs, but when I put the script into the docker file it reports that mariadb got a 127 error. I have tried putting the call to mysqld inside of the script, but that has not fixed the issue.
Dockerfile

```
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydatabase

COPY . /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN script_runner.sh test 
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

script_runner.sh

```
files=`ls start_script | grep ^'do'`
for script in $files
do
mysql -u root --password=$1 < `pwd`/start_script/$script
done
```

docker-compose.yml

```
...
mariadb:
        build:
            context: ./mariaDB
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "/srv/docker/sockets/mariadb.container.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld"
```

file system

```
-repo/
--docker-compose.yml
--mariadb/
---Dockerfile
---script_runner.sh
----start_script/
----do-release.sql
```

error

```
Building mariadb
Step 1/8 : FROM mariadb:10.4.11-bionic
 ---> bc20d5f8d0fe
Step 2/8 : ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test
 ---> Running in 5987d662632b
Removing intermediate container 5987d662632b
 ---> e40256430e39
Step 3/8 : ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydatabase
 ---> Running in a865ef21cdcc
Removing intermediate container a865ef21cdcc
 ---> dc5997996fef
Step 4/8 : COPY . /usr/src
 ---> 5314d67545bb
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src
 ---> Running in 4643fe58e44e
Removing intermediate container 4643fe58e44e
 ---> 88e7901d501a
Step 6/8 : RUN script_runner.sh test
 ---> Running in 502ab4fddbb8
/bin/sh: 1: script_runner.sh: not found
ERROR: Service 'mariadb' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c script_runner.sh test' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel. Go to [image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/), look for "Initializing a fresh instance". Extract: `...Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` Read the rest for more info. Simply copy or mount your files there and you are done.

Comment: I need to run this every time this spins up. The scripts don't input data just ensure that the table structure is correct

Comment: From your above example and output, your script runs only once at build time. Moreover, your script is expecting to connect to mysql... which is not started when you build. It will only get up and running when a container starts off the image and launches the entrypoint script and command.

Answer (score 0):

Your `script_runner.sh` file needs executable permissions, otherwise it will not be found as executable. Try setting the attribute in your local folder (chmod 7xx) or inside the Dockerfile

```
COPY . /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN chmod 711 script_runner.sh
RUN script_runner.sh test
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that says you need to make the script_runner.sh script executable and that would likely be the cause of the 127 return code. However I think you'll find it still won't work even after making it executable.

At the time the `RUN script_runner.sh test` gets executed, the MySQL server won't actually running yet inside the Docker container during the build process. So if you made the script executable I think you'll see that it'll return a "cannot connect to mysql sock" type error. You'd have to start mysqld as part of your Docker build. Also, remember that a docker build will execute each RUN statement by itself and make a layer of the disk changes after that command finishes. If you simply try to issue a `RUN mysqld` (or similar), either the mysqld process will start and block forever (assuming it doesn't daemonize) or (if you tell it to daemonize) it will start and as soon as it moves to the background, docker will make a layer of the disk and then execute your `script_runner.sh` but mysql will have exited.

If you want to do this you have two options:

1. Combine the two into a single RUN statement such as `RUN mysqld_safe && script_runner.sh`
2. Have your script_runner.sh start mysqld before it tries to execute the mysql client.

Either way should work and would (I think) end up with the same single layer of disk changes. The documents touch on this in their best practices recommendations (although here they're trying to minimize the number of layers for performance reasons):

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers